# Comparing the group convolution algebra with the equivariant Roe algebra

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, lie-groups, oa.operator-algebras, coarse-geometry

Let $G$ be a Lie group equipped with a left-invariant metric. Then $C_c(G)$ is a $*$-algebra of convolution operators on $L^2(G)$.

Let $\mathbb{C}[|G|]^G$ denote the $*$-subalgebra of bounded operators $T$ on $L^2(G)$ that:

- commute with the action of $G$ on $L^2(G)$ by translation;
- have finite propagation, meaning there exists $r>0$ such that for any $a,b\in C_c(G)$ with $\text{dist}(\text{supp}(a),\text{supp}(b))>r$, we have $aTb=0$, where $a$ and $b$ act as bounded operators by pointwise multiplication;
- are locally compact, meaning that for any $a\in C_c(G)$ we have $aT, Ta\in\mathcal{K}(L^2(G))$.

We have an injective $*$-homomorphism $C_c(G)\hookrightarrow\mathbb{C}[|G|]^G$ given by taking $f$ to the convolution operator it defines. Furthermore, the image of $C_c(G)$ is dense inside $\mathbb{C}[G]^G$ with respect to the operator norm, so that, with respect to this norm, both algebras complete to the reduced group $C^*$-algebra $C^*_r(G)\subseteq\mathcal{B}(L^2(G))$.

I would like to know understand more about the **maximal** completions of these two $*$-algebras. More precisely, define the *maximal norm* of an element $f\in C_c(G)$ to be

$$||f||_{\text{max}}:=\sup_{\phi,H}\left\{||\phi(f)||_{\mathcal{B}(H)}:\phi:C_c(G)\rightarrow H\text{ is a $*$-homomorphism}\right\}.$$

In particular, this quantity is finite because $||f||_{\text{max}}\leq||f||_{L^1(G)}.$

Analogously, we can try to define a maximal norm for an element $T\in\mathbb{C}[G]^G$:

$$||T||_{\text{max}}:=\sup_{\phi,H}\left\{||\phi(T)||_{\mathcal{B}(H)}:\phi:\mathbb{C}[|G|]^G\rightarrow H\text{ is a $*$-homomorphism}\right\},$$

although it is not clear to me that this is finite.

I would like to know:

**Question 1:** Is every $T\in\mathbb{C}[|G|]^G$ given by a Schwartz kernel?

**Question 2:** Is it known that the maximal norm is finite for every $T\in\mathbb{C}[|G|]^G$?

**Question 3:** If the answer to the previous question is yes, is it true that the maximal completion of $\mathbb{C}[G]^G$ is isomorphic to the maximal group $C^*$-algebra $C^*_{\text{max}}(G)$?

*Remark:* The case of $G$ discrete seems to have been dealt with in detail in the literature. In that case, both $C_c(G)$ and $\mathbb{C}[|G|]^G$ are just the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$, so the answers to the the three questions above are all yes. In particular, this allows us to write any $T$ as a finite sum of elements with whose $l^1$-norms we can estimate.

Comment: What does it mean for $a,b\in C_c(G)$ to be "separated by a distance $r$"?

Comment: I've edited the question; hopefully it's clearer now.